Spring AOP advice on @Service methods
Could someone please suggest why this aspect doesn't catch @Service methods?
My guess is that @Service classes are already proxied and there is some clash with the advice, if it works so - how to fix it?
@Aspect
@Component
public class PostPreAuthorizeServiceAdvice {

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service) && execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(preAuthorize)", throwing = "ex")
    public void checkPreAuthorizeAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, PreAuthorize preAuthorize, Throwable ex) throws Throwable {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }

    @Around("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service) && @annotation(preAuthorize)")
    public Object parsePreAuthorize(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, PreAuthorize preAuthorize) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }
    }

}

Thank you!

It is hard to reason about an aspect in isolation without resorting to speculation. I, however, prefer analysis to guessing around. Please provide an MCVE. Thank you.

you have to use fully qualified class name with @annotation, in this case @Around("@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Service) && @annotation(org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize)")

@JAsgarov thanks for the reply, unfortunately not, it works in such form as well, once I remove designator for @Service
